# What happens between after_validation and before_save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The `after_validation` callback is triggered before `before_save`. What happens between those callbacks, if anything? Why would one choose one over another?

Comment: `after_validation` will be called if you call `#valid?` so there may be instances where you only want to check the validity of a record but still run something after validation.  In my experience, I've never had a chance to use `after_validation`.

Comment: In addition to what jvnill said, an object is not saved if it is not valid. Therefore, calling save on an invalid object will not trigger the `before_save` callback, whereas it will trigger `after_validation`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an `after_validation_on_update` or `after_validation_on_create` depending if the item is a new record.

And as Max states, the chain is interrupted before it reaches the `before_save` callback if the object is not valid, so if you need something to occur regardless of the validity of the object `before_save` is not the place for it.

For reference:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_validation_on_create

Answer (score 3):

`after_validation_on_create` and `after_validation_on_update` were removed from Rails 3.0.

New syntax form:

```
after_validation
after_validation, on: :update  # or :update
after_validation, on: [ :create, :update ]
```

Now nothing is executed between them.

Adding excellent comments to an answer:

"`after_validation` will be called if you call `#valid?` so there may be instances where you only want to check the validity of a record but still run something after validation. In my experience, I've never had a chance to use `after_validation`." @jvnill

"In addition to what jvnill said, an object is not saved if it is not valid. Therefore, calling save on an invalid object will not trigger the `before_save` callback, whereas it will trigger `after_validation`." @Max